# LARAVEL 9 The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm only getting an error while trying to update the data. I'm using post method not the push. I've tried to add @method('PUT') but that didn't work, too.

Creating new category just works fine as it should do but when I try to edit something it just throws the error. Also I tried to use route::put but that didn't work.

My CategoryController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $data = Category::all();
        return view('admin.category.index', [
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.category.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = new Category;
        $data->parent_id = 1;
        $data->title = $request->title;
        $data->keywords = $request->keywords;
        $data->description = $request->description;
        $data->status = $request->status;
        $data->save();
        return redirect('admin/category');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Category $category)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Category $category, $id)
    {
        //
        $data = Category::find($id);
        return view('admin.category.edit', [
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Category $category, $id)
    {
        //
        $data = Category::find($id);
        $data->parent_id = 1;
        $data->title = $request->title;
        $data->keywords = $request->keywords;
        $data->description = $request->description;
        $data->status = $request->status;
        $data->save();
        return redirect('admin/category');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Category $category)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

MY edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.adminbase')

@section('title', 'Edit Category')

@section('content')
            <!-- Begin Page Content -->
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Edit Category: {{$data -> title}}</h1>

                <!-- Collapsable Card-->
                <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                    <!-- Card Header - Accordion -->
                    <a href="#collapseCardExample" class="d-block card-header py-3" data-toggle="collapse"
                       role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCardExample">
                        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Category Elements</h6>
                    </a>
                    <!-- Card Content - Collapse -->
                    <div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="/admin/category/update/{{$data->id}}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{$data->title}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Keywords</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywords" value="{{$data->keywords}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Description</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{$data->description}}">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputFile">Image</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="custom-file">
                                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="image">
                                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose image file</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Status</label>
                                        <select class="custom-select" name="status">
                                            <option selected>{{$data->status}}</option>
                                            <option>Enable</option>
                                            <option>Disable</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                <!-- /.card-body -->

                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Data</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Main Content -->

@endsection
```

My routes

```
// Admin category routes
Route::get('/admin/category', [AdminCategoryController::class,'index'] )->name('admin_category');
Route::get('/admin/category/create', [AdminCategoryController::class,'create'] )->name('admin_category_create');
Route::post('/admin/category/store', [AdminCategoryController::class,'store'] )->name('admin_category_store');
Route::get('/admin/category/edit/{id}', [AdminCategoryController::class,'edit'] )->name('admin_category_edit');
Route::post('/admin/category/update/{id}', [AdminCategoryController::class,'edit'] )->name('admin_category_update');
```

Comment: Not sure what I did but now I'm not getting an error now but I still can't update the table it just reloads the page and table is still the same. It must return back to category page.

Comment: For update you should have update function in route definition.

Comment: @nikistag I updated it. Check the CategoryController.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make these modifications to your code:
edit.blade:

```
 <form action="/admin/category/update/{{$data->id}}" method="POST">
 @csrf
 @method('PUT')
 .........
```

Route:

```
Route::put('/admin/category/update/{id}', [AdminCategoryController::class,'update'] )->name('admin_category_update');
```

Check if it works.

One more thing: If you correctly created [model binding](https:///https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding), your update function could look like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Category $category, $id)
{
    //
    $category->parent_id = 1;
    $category->title = $request->title;
    $category->keywords = $request->keywords;
    $category->description = $request->description;
    $category->status = $request->status;
    $category->save();
    return redirect('admin/category');
}
```

That is because you already have the model right there: `public function update(Request $request, **Category $category**, $id)`

Comment: If model binding is correctly set, along with the Request you also have the specific Category as $category, fresh from database. So you can play with it: $category->title = 'some change'; $category->save(); OR just $category->delete()