# Can't access Update function of the controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So when I try to access the update function inside a resource controller, when I hit submit to go there (posts/{id}) I go to the show function of the controller (witch has the same path (posts/{id}).
How can I go the the update path, and access the update function?

So here is the view with its from of the edit function, that will "update" the title:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <h1>Edit Post</h1>

    <form method="get" action="/posts/{{$post->id}}">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter title" value="{{$post->title}}">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

@endsection
```

And here is the update function of the controller, that will get the values from the upper view and update the post with that id:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

And this is the show function that is going to run after I hit submit, instead of the update:

```
public function show($id)
{
    //
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

The view of show function, in case you need it:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>

@endsection
```

When I hit submit it should check first the update function of controller, and render its code, because both update function and show function have the same path posts/{id}.
[image]

Comment: Use `method="post"` instead of `method="get"`

Comment: "_because both update function and show function have the same path posts/{id}_" You can't have two routes pointing to the same url unless they have different request types (get, post ...)

Comment: I tried <form method='put' too. But It didn't work!

Comment: There is no `method="put"`, it's `method="post"`. Then use `@method('PUT')` in your form

Comment: You mean like this <form method='post@method('PUT')' ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LARAVEL 9 The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547980/laravel-9-the-put-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get)

Comment: Below @csrf I need to put @method('PUT') ?

Comment: @GjinKurtishi Yes, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have in the web.php file the POST path so you should change the method tag of your form in this way:

```
<form method="POST">
```

Remove the invisible field where you specify a method, that's not how it's done.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Next I recommend that you use the route() function to specify which route you want to make the request to. This way you can use the names of your routes.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.update', ['id' => $post->id]) }}">
```

In your web.php file you must specify your update path as follows:

```
Route::post('update/{id}', [PostsController::class, 'update'])->name('posts.update');
```

I hope it has helped you.

Comment: Based on conventions, *'update'* based routes should use `Route::put(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of `method="get"`, use `method="post"` if u already used get for show function, because both show and update have the same path: `posts/{$id}`.